# How to dynamically change xslt page-sequence based on node attributes?

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

The watered-down version of the problem I'm having is this. For an XML file like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<items>
    <item cols="1">Item 1</item>
    <item cols="1">Item 2</item>
    <item cols="1">Item 3</item>
    <item cols="1">Item 4</item>
    <item cols="1">Item 5</item>
    <item cols="1">Item 6</item>
    <item cols="1">Item 7</item>
    <item cols="1">Item 8</item>
    <item cols="1">Item 9</item>
    <item cols="2">Item 10</item>
    <item cols="1">Item 11</item>
    <item cols="1">Item 12</item>
    <item cols="1">Item 13</item>
    <item cols="1">Item 14</item>
    <item cols="1">Item 15</item>
    <item cols="1">Item 16</item>
    <item cols="1">Item 17</item>
    <item cols="1">Item 18</item>
</items>
```

I need to be able to print the 'item's that have 'cols=1' in a single column page layout, and the 'item's that have 'cols=2' in a double column page layout. The ordering of the items has to be preserved. All contiguous 'item's with the same value of @cols needs to appear as a continuous flow. Any time the @cols value changes, I need to break to a new page and change the layout as necessary.

I'm doing something like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
            <fo:layout-master-set>

                <fo:simple-page-master master-name="one-column-page-master">
                    <fo:region-body margin-top="3cm" region-name="body" column-count="1"/>
                </fo:simple-page-master>

                <fo:simple-page-master master-name="two-column-page-master">
                    <fo:region-body margin-top="3cm" region-name="body" column-count="2"/>
                    <fo:region-before region-name="header" extent="2cm"/>
                </fo:simple-page-master>

                <fo:page-sequence-master master-name="one-column-page">
                    <fo:repeatable-page-master-reference master-reference="one-column-page-master"/>
                </fo:page-sequence-master>

                <fo:page-sequence-master master-name="two-column-page">
                    <fo:repeatable-page-master-reference master-reference="two-column-page-master"/>
                </fo:page-sequence-master>

            </fo:layout-master-set>

            <xsl:for-each select="//item">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="@cols = preceding-sibling::item[1]/@cols">
                        <!--cols value hasn't changed, don't create a new page-sequence-->
                        <!--But we cannot directly add fo:flow as the child of fo:root! -->
                        <xsl:call-template name="itemtemplate"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="@cols = 1">
                                <fo:page-sequence master-reference="one-column-page">
                                    <xsl:call-template name="itemtemplate"/>
                                </fo:page-sequence>
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                <fo:page-sequence master-reference="two-column-page">
                                    <xsl:call-template name="itemtemplate"/>
                                </fo:page-sequence>
                            </xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </fo:root>

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="itemtemplate">
            <fo:flow flow-name="body">
                <fo:block margin-bottom="5cm">
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </fo:block>
            </fo:flow>

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But of course, the problem is that I either have to include a <fo:page-sequence..> in my stylesheet, or not, I cannot 'dynamically' decide to put in one based on note attributes. (Unless I have a meta program that creates the stylesheet dynamically in the first place, but I was hoping to accomplish this using just plain static stylesheets).

Comment: Good question. I wonder if the grouping features of XSLT 2.0 would solve this problem for you. Please show the desired output XML (FO) for your sample input, so we can better understand what target you are aiming for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an XSLT 2.0 solution that uses [`xsl:for-each-group`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#xsl-for-each-group) with `group-adjacent`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
        <fo:layout-master-set>

          <fo:simple-page-master master-name="one-column-page-master">
            <fo:region-body margin-top="3cm" region-name="body" 
                            column-count="1"/>
          </fo:simple-page-master>

          <fo:simple-page-master master-name="two-column-page-master">
            <fo:region-body margin-top="3cm" region-name="body" 
                            column-count="2"/>
            <fo:region-before region-name="header" extent="2cm"/>
          </fo:simple-page-master>

          <fo:page-sequence-master master-name="one-column-page">
            <fo:repeatable-page-master-reference 
                master-reference="one-column-page-master"/>
          </fo:page-sequence-master>

          <fo:page-sequence-master master-name="two-column-page">
            <fo:repeatable-page-master-reference 
                master-reference="two-column-page-master"/>
          </fo:page-sequence-master>

        </fo:layout-master-set>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </fo:root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="items">
      <xsl:for-each-group select="item" 
                          group-adjacent="@cols">

        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="@cols = 1">
            <fo:page-sequence master-reference="one-column-page">
              <fo:flow flow-name="body">
                <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
                </xsl:for-each>
              </fo:flow>
            </fo:page-sequence>
          </xsl:when>

          <xsl:otherwise>
            <fo:page-sequence master-reference="two-column-page">
              <fo:flow flow-name="body">
                <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
                </xsl:for-each>
              </fo:flow>
            </fo:page-sequence>
          </xsl:otherwise>

        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="item">
      <fo:block margin-bottom="5cm">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </fo:block>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
   <fo:layout-master-set>
      <fo:simple-page-master master-name="one-column-page-master">
         <fo:region-body margin-top="3cm" region-name="body" column-count="1"/>
      </fo:simple-page-master>
      <fo:simple-page-master master-name="two-column-page-master">
         <fo:region-body margin-top="3cm" region-name="body" column-count="2"/>
         <fo:region-before region-name="header" extent="2cm"/>
      </fo:simple-page-master>
      <fo:page-sequence-master master-name="one-column-page">
         <fo:repeatable-page-master-reference master-reference="one-column-page-master"/>
      </fo:page-sequence-master>
      <fo:page-sequence-master master-name="two-column-page">
         <fo:repeatable-page-master-reference master-reference="two-column-page-master"/>
      </fo:page-sequence-master>
   </fo:layout-master-set>
   <fo:page-sequence master-reference="one-column-page">
      <fo:flow flow-name="body">
         <fo:block margin-bottom="5cm">Item 1</fo:block>
         <fo:block margin-bottom="5cm">Item 2</fo:block>
         <fo:block margin-bottom="5cm">Item 3</fo:block>
         <fo:block margin-bottom="5cm">Item 4</fo:block>
         <fo:block margin-bottom="5cm">Item 5</fo:block>
         <fo:block margin-bottom="5cm">Item 6</fo:block>
         <fo:block margin-bottom="5cm">Item 7</fo:block>
         <fo:block margin-bottom="5cm">Item 8</fo:block>
         <fo:block margin-bottom="5cm">Item 9</fo:block>
      </fo:flow>
   </fo:page-sequence>
   <fo:page-sequence master-reference="two-column-page">
      <fo:flow flow-name="body">
         <fo:block margin-bottom="5cm">Item 10</fo:block>
      </fo:flow>
   </fo:page-sequence>
   <fo:page-sequence master-reference="one-column-page">
      <fo:flow flow-name="body">
         <fo:block margin-bottom="5cm">Item 11</fo:block>
         <fo:block margin-bottom="5cm">Item 12</fo:block>
         <fo:block margin-bottom="5cm">Item 13</fo:block>
         <fo:block margin-bottom="5cm">Item 14</fo:block>
         <fo:block margin-bottom="5cm">Item 15</fo:block>
         <fo:block margin-bottom="5cm">Item 16</fo:block>
         <fo:block margin-bottom="5cm">Item 17</fo:block>
         <fo:block margin-bottom="5cm">Item 18</fo:block>
      </fo:flow>
   </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
```

Answer (score 2):

> ***I need to be able to print the 'item's that have 'cols=1' in a single column page layout, and the 'item's that have 'cols=2' in a double column page layout. The ordering of the items has to be preserved.***

You want finally group adjacent `item` elements according the value of `@cols` in the proper fo page sequence.

XSLT 1.0 instructions like `xsl:choose` and `xsl:for-each` are not really suitable to this task. I think you have to change your mind a bit. Here an example of how to achieve the result grouping by recursion.

It's not really clear what you want to include inside each flow element, then I decided to show you just how to group elements; then, you can adapt the code to your requirements.

---

[XSLT 1.0]

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="text()"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <fo:root>
            <!-- layout master stuff -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="item"/>
        </fo:root>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- match @cols 1, first group occurrences -->  
    <xsl:template match="/*/item[@cols=1]
     [not(preceding-sibling::item[1][@cols=1])]">
        <fo:page-sequence master-reference="one-column-page">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="
                following-sibling::*[1][self::item[@cols=1]]" mode="flow">
                <xsl:with-param name="cols" select="1"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </fo:page-sequence>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- match @cols 2, first group occurrences -->
    <xsl:template match="/*/item[@cols=2]
     [not(preceding-sibling::item[1][@cols=2])]">
        <fo:page-sequence master-reference="two-column-page">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="
                following-sibling::*[1][self::item[@cols=2]]" mode="flow">
                <xsl:with-param name="cols" select="2"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </fo:page-sequence>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- recursive match adjacent @cols -->
    <xsl:template match="item" mode="flow">
        <xsl:param name="cols"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="
            following-sibling::*[1][self::item[@cols=$cols]]" mode="flow">
            <xsl:with-param name="cols" select="$cols"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to the sample input provided in the question produces:

```
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
   <fo:page-sequence master-reference="one-column-page">
      <item cols="1">Item 1</item>
      <item cols="1">Item 2</item>
      <item cols="1">Item 3</item>
      <item cols="1">Item 4</item>
      <item cols="1">Item 5</item>
      <item cols="1">Item 6</item>
      <item cols="1">Item 7</item>
      <item cols="1">Item 8</item>
      <item cols="1">Item 9</item>
   </fo:page-sequence>
   <fo:page-sequence master-reference="two-column-page">
      <item cols="2">Item 10</item>
   </fo:page-sequence>
   <fo:page-sequence master-reference="one-column-page">
      <item cols="1">Item 11</item>
      <item cols="1">Item 12</item>
      <item cols="1">Item 13</item>
      <item cols="1">Item 14</item>
      <item cols="1">Item 15</item>
      <item cols="1">Item 16</item>
      <item cols="1">Item 17</item>
      <item cols="1">Item 18</item>
   </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
```

Answer (score 1):

@empo: Excellent! So the basic approach is to handle the critical 'item's (where @cols changes) in the main loop, and handle the adjacent nodes to these in the recursive template call. I've used your approach and made a few changes to make the code simpler, but this works great!

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="text()"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <fo:root>

            <xsl:for-each select="item">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="preceding-sibling::item[1]/@cols != @cols or position()=1">
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="@cols = 1">
                                <fo:page-sequence master-reference="one-column-page">
                                    <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="recurse">
                                        <xsl:with-param name="cols" select="@cols"/>
                                    </xsl:apply-templates>
                                </fo:page-sequence>

                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:when test="@cols = 2">
                                <fo:page-sequence master-reference="two-column-page">
                                    <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="recurse">
                                        <xsl:with-param name="cols" select="@cols"/>
                                    </xsl:apply-templates>
                                </fo:page-sequence>
                            </xsl:when>
                        </xsl:choose>
                    </xsl:when>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </fo:root>
    </xsl:template>


    <!-- recursive match adjacent @cols -->
    <xsl:template match="item" mode="recurse">
        <xsl:param name="cols"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="
            following-sibling::*[1][self::item[@cols=$cols]]"
            mode="recurse">
            <xsl:with-param name="cols" select="$cols"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. So why you accepted the other answer?