# How to align figure/table to the top or bottom of the page in XSL-FO (FOP 2.1)

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

In the case figure or table is a bit larger it would be really suitable to move them to the top or the bottom of the page. The ability to reflow table to the next page with repeating its headers is great but not always what I want. In the case table or figure fits well in the page and it is not necessarily anchored to a paragraph, there is no reason to reflow it. It would be better to make it “floating” outside the body of the page.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6842089/4120271) is really inspiring but I am not sure how to apply it to my case. I would be happy if I could do it according to a `@rendition` attribute of the table.

```
<fo:layout-master-set>
    <fo:simple-page-master master-name="PageMaster.Title-Page" page-height="{$paper-height}" page-width="{$paper-width}" margin-left="{$margin-left}" margin-right="{$margin-right}" margin-top="{$margin-top}" margin-bottom="{$margin-bottom}">
        <fo:region-body/>
    </fo:simple-page-master>
    <fo:simple-page-master master-name="PageMaster.CopyRight-Page" page-height="{$paper-height}" page-width="{$paper-width}" margin-left="{$margin-left}" margin-right="{$margin-right}" margin-top="{$margin-top}" margin-bottom="{$margin-bottom}">
        <fo:region-body display-align="after"/>
    </fo:simple-page-master>
    <fo:simple-page-master master-name="PageMaster.TOC" page-height="{$paper-height}" page-width="{$paper-width}" margin-left="{$margin-left}" margin-right="{$margin-right}" margin-top="18mm" margin-bottom="{$margin-bottom}">
        <fo:region-body margin="0mm 0mm 0mm 60mm"/>
    </fo:simple-page-master><!-- Whole page left and right masters -->
    <fo:simple-page-master master-name="PageMaster.Page-Right.First" page-height="{$paper-height}" page-width="{$paper-width}" margin-left="{$margin-left}" margin-right="{$margin-right}" margin-top="{$margin-top}" margin-bottom="{$margin-bottom}">
        <fo:region-body margin="8mm 0mm 20mm 0mm" column-count="2" column-gap="5mm"/>
        <fo:region-before region-name="Region-Before-Right" extent="10mm" display-align="after"/>
        <fo:region-after region-name="Region-After-First" extent="20mm" display-align="before"/>
    </fo:simple-page-master>
    <fo:simple-page-master master-name="PageMaster.Page-Left" page-height="{$paper-height}" page-width="{$paper-width}" margin-left="{$margin-left}" margin-right="{$margin-right}" margin-top="{$margin-top}" margin-bottom="{$margin-bottom}">
        <fo:region-body margin="8mm 0mm 20mm 0mm" column-count="2" column-gap="5mm"/>
        <fo:region-before region-name="Region-Before-Left" extent="10mm" display-align="after"/>
    </fo:simple-page-master>
    <fo:simple-page-master master-name="PageMaster.Page-Right" page-height="{$paper-height}" page-width="{$paper-width}" margin-left="{$margin-left}" margin-right="{$margin-right}" margin-top="{$margin-top}" margin-bottom="{$margin-bottom}">
        <fo:region-body margin="8mm 0mm 20mm 0mm" column-count="2" column-gap="5mm"/>
        <fo:region-before region-name="Region-Before-Right" extent="10mm" display-align="after"/>
    </fo:simple-page-master>
    <fo:simple-page-master master-name="PageMaster.Blank" page-height="{$paper-height}" page-width="{$paper-width}" margin-left="{$margin-left}" margin-right="{$margin-right}" margin-top="{$margin-top}" margin-bottom="{$margin-bottom}">
        <fo:region-body margin="8mm 0mm 20mm 0mm" column-count="2" column-gap="5mm"/>
    </fo:simple-page-master><!-- Sequence of even / odd pages -->
    <fo:page-sequence-master master-name="Content-Pages">
        <fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
            <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="PageMaster.Blank" blank-or-not-blank="blank"/>
            <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="PageMaster.Page-Right.First" odd-or-even="odd" page-position="first"/>
            <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="PageMaster.Page-Left" odd-or-even="even"/>
            <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="PageMaster.Page-Right" odd-or-even="odd"/>
        </fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
    </fo:page-sequence-master>
</fo:layout-master-set>
```

Comment: It sounds like you want `fo:float` (https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_float).  However, it appears that FOP can only float to the left or right: https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/fo.html#floats.  Other FO formatters can float content to the top of the page (and some also to the bottom of the page).

Comment: The statement ... "The ability to reflow table to the next page with repeating its headers is great but not always what I want." implies exactly what XSL FO is not designed to do ... it cannot read your mind nor desires. If you cannot explicitly describe what the "rules" are, then you cannot create a solution that predicts "not always what you want"

Comment: @KevinBrown Of course, hence I wrote “I would be happy if I could do it according to a `@rendition` attribute of the table.” I use it similarly for changing table’s span across two columns.

Comment: @TonyGraham Thank you, I had the suspicion. It seems this could be a limit for me (I use FOP because of eXist-db).

Comment: I know RenderX XEP integrates perfect with exist. I use it every day. I would think Antenna has a similar integration

Comment: @KevinBrown I would be very happy if you could suggest how to try RenderX in eXist. I tried that a couple of months ago without success. As for AH formatter, I think it is not easy to integrate it on a Linux machine. Any hints more than welcome.

Comment: Best for offline as this is not the original question ... kevin@renderx.com ... or post a new question as to how to integrate and I will post detailed response.

Comment: @KevinBrown PM sent, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Tony Graham commented, **FOP does not support *before floats* yet** (strangely enough, it silently swallows them without a warning).

However, **you could use *footnotes* instead** to place your tables at the bottom of the pages in which they are referenced. If I remember correctly, FOP favours placing the footnotes in their entirety over adding more "flowing" content, so the result *should* be the expected one.

**FO example:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:simple-page-master master-name="simple" page-width="14.85cm" page-height="21cm">
            <fo:region-body margin="1in"/>
        </fo:simple-page-master>
    </fo:layout-master-set>

    <fo:page-sequence master-reference="simple">
        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body" text-align="justify">
            <fo:block>Maecenas lectus nisl, pulvinar at tincidunt a, semper sit amet nibh. Morbi at dolor quis sem porta volutpat. Quisque eget magna lectus. Donec laoreet congue enim ut ullamcorper. Ut vestibulum consequat neque rhoncus laoreet.</fo:block>
            <fo:block>Here is a block referring to a <fo:footnote><fo:inline font-weight="bold">TABLE 1</fo:inline><fo:footnote-body>
                <fo:block font-weight="bold">TABLE 1:</fo:block>
                <fo:table width="100%" table-layout="fixed">
                    <fo:table-column column-width="30%"/>
                    <fo:table-column column-width="70%"/>
                    <fo:table-body>
                        <fo:table-row>
                            <fo:table-cell><fo:block>A</fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell><fo:block>132</fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                        </fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-row>
                            <fo:table-cell><fo:block>B</fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell><fo:block>556638</fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                        </fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-row>
                            <fo:table-cell><fo:block>C</fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell><fo:block>574</fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                        </fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-row>
                            <fo:table-cell><fo:block>D</fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell><fo:block>8893</fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                        </fo:table-row>
                    </fo:table-body>
                </fo:table>
            </fo:footnote-body></fo:footnote>; the table should be in the same page as the bolded part.</fo:block>
            <fo:block>This is another block of content. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In tincidunt ipsum eget nisl iaculis fringilla. Pellentesque sagittis quam tellus, ac varius nisl rutrum non. Phasellus eget imperdiet velit.</fo:block>
            <fo:block>Aenean eleifend, arcu et feugiat facilisis, diam orci luctus lectus, id laoreet ex risus sed nunc. Proin eget scelerisque orci. Donec porttitor tellus libero, a molestie orci vestibulum mattis. Ut eu massa ac massa sagittis molestie. Quisque viverra ipsum vel mauris laoreet aliquet.</fo:block>
            <fo:block>Maecenas lectus nisl, pulvinar at tincidunt a, semper sit amet nibh. Morbi at dolor quis sem porta volutpat. Quisque eget magna lectus. Donec laoreet congue enim ut ullamcorper. Ut vestibulum consequat neque rhoncus laoreet.</fo:block>
            <fo:block> Sed ipsum massa, maximus eget posuere et, pellentesque accumsan nulla. Vestibulum erat mauris, imperdiet at mattis in, rhoncus eget orci. Nullam rhoncus hendrerit magna. </fo:block>  
        </fo:flow>
    </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
```

**Resulting output:**

[image: PDF screenshot]

The downside of using footnotes is that the constraint on footnote placement is **more strict** than the one on before floats (which can be placed in a page *following* their anchor-area, as per [section 6.12.2 of the recommentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/#fo_float)), so there could be layout problems (empty areas in the pages) if the input has many tables cited in a sequence of paragraphs.

*(disclosure: I am a FOP developer, though not very active nowadays)*